# PHP Date Format Issue

Tags: php

I have date in following format (Y-m-d) as 2010-11-24, need to convert it to 
1) 24 Nov, 2010
2) 24_Nov_2010

Help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. (d M, Y)
> 2. (d_M_Y)

So, something like

```
date("d M, Y");
```

Will output todays date:

> 24 Nov, 2010

**Edit:** I may have read your question incorrectly. Can you please clarify if this is what you want? Or you wanted to convert the `24-11-2010` into the above formats?

If the latter if what you were seeking, you can simply utilise the `strtotime` function:

```
date("d M, Y", strtotime("2010-11-24"));
```

Comment: I need to convert 2010-11-24 or any other date, but in format YYYY-MM-DD (which is returned from Database) to above mentioned format.

Answer (score 2):

```
$oDate = new DateTime('2010-11-24');
echo $oDate->format('d M, Y') . "\n";
echo $oDate->format('d_M_Y') . "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Most simple, you can use *strtotime*() to convert 2010-11-24 into date, and use *date*() to get seperate pieces(Y,m,D) and convert them to whatever format you want.

Please refer this link:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 1):

```
$d1 = "2010-11-24";

echo date("d M, Y", strtotime($d1));   // 24 Nov, 2010
echo date("d_M_Y", strtotime($d1));    // 24_Nov_2010
```